# Simple cv in Raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, simplecv

I type following code in my raspberry pi.

```
from SimpleCV import Camera
# Initialize the camera
cam = Camera()
# Loop to continuously get images
while True:
    # Get Image from camera
    img = cam.getImage()
    # Show the image
    img.show()
```

But when i run on python(installed in raspberry pi), First time it run very well. But when I run it again it says camera driver not detected error. I use a web cam as my camera. OS is raspbian.

Comment: I took the liberty of removed lines of code in the sample you've given that are completely unrelated to the problem you've having.  Please verify that the issue still exists with the updated code (or revert my changes).  Thank you.

Comment: yes that error still exsists.

Comment: SimpleCV with raspberry pie have been facing such issues. Add a time delay after each time you grab the image.